# Issue when deploy angular 6 app on aws ec2 instance for live

Tags: amazon-ec2, angular6, instance, web-deployment

I want to deploy my angular app on live. I have run this command for make a build

```
ng build --prod // to make a production build.
```

Then after I have update the `index.html` in dist folder.

```
<base href="http://0.0.0.0:4200/adminpanel/">
```

**Note:** I have set my elastic IP address instead of 0.0.0.0.

I have make a zip of the dist folder and upload on `server.`

```
var/www/html/adminpanel.zip
```

Then unzip the file. then rename folder from `dist` to `adminpanel`.

Done.

After that I have call URL from browser. Then it shows

> Site can't be reached

I think I have done all steps correctly. Can any one help me what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, have you created `.htaccess` file after project uploaded?

Comment: I have add it , still not works. It may be possible that my .htaccess is wrong.

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /adminpanel/index.html [NC,L]` Note that `adminpanel` is name of project directory that you've uploaded! Let me know if this works.

Comment: ok thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have update `BaseURL` in build dist folder.

```
<base href="http://0.0.0.0/adminpanel/">
```

And also handle all admin panel API req to this way.

```
app.use('/adminpanel' , require('./routes/router'));
```

Now it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code into your`.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /adminpanel/index.html [NC,L]
```

**Note**:  `adminpanel` is the name of the project directory that you've uploaded code!

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I have also marked that in network it shows status failed for my aws elastic ip.

Comment: Then first check the ec2 instance status from aws console, then you might got success! https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html

Comment: Now I have fixed issue. It was issue in baseURL.And also I have update app in node. And set the routing path.

Comment: Okay, then didn't need to set `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I have still set for safer side.:)